On multivariable extension of $g=f' \iff \int g=0$ for Schwartz functions $g,f$
Let $g \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ Then, it is well-known that there exists another $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f'=g$ iff $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g=0$.
I wonder if this result extends to multivariable cases too.
More specifically, let $g \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ be such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x_1,x_2)dx^1=0$ for all $x_2$. Then, we do have a function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $x_1 \to f(x_1,x_2)$ is Schwartz for each $x_2$ and $\partial_1 f = g$. However,

Is this $f$ a Schwartz function on whole $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I suspect so, but it seems trickier than expected to come up with any proof..
Could anyone help me?

What is the source of the difficulty?

@TedShifrin I do not see any control over dependence of $f$ on the argument $x_2$.

Certainly you do, since $\partial f/\partial x_2$ is given by integrating the Schwartz function $\partial g/\partial x_2$. Can you be more specific?

@TedShifrin Oh...thank you. I was careless...
